# How to search item of collection with key?

Tags: php, laravel

I got the following collection:

```
$this->items = collect([$productId => [
                    'name' => $product->title,
                    'price' => $product->price,
                    'is_sale' => $product->is_sale,
                    'sale_price' => $product->sale_price,
                    'sale_percent' => $product->sale_percent,
                    'can_use_promocode' => $product->can_use_promocode,
                    'qty' => 1,
                ]);
]);
```

How to search an item with key? In documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections) I dont see any methods for it

UPD: For example, user added an item to cart (`$this->items`). I want to check existence of item in cart (need to do it with key). Analog for php function `array_key_exists`, but for collections.

Comment: what do you want to search here??

Comment: @Sohel0415 check the question, updated :)

Comment: do you want to search it, with which one of the keys?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use [has()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-has)

```
if($this->items->has('key_name_to_check')){
    ///your task if exists
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
$this->items->toArray()[$key]
```

Or you can use the [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-first) method:

```
$this->items->first(function($i, $k) use($key) {
    return $key === $k;
});
```

**Update**

If you just want to know if an item with given key exists in the collection, you can use the `offsetExists()` method.

The `offsetExists()` method is full analog of `array_key_exists()`, because all it does is this:

```
return array_key_exists($key, $this->items);
```

Comment: something method like `array_key_exists` is not exist for collections? :(

Comment: @Alexxosipov `offsetExists()` is analog for `array_key_exists()`, but it's for collections.

Comment: Oh, as @Sohel0415 said, I can just use has() for it :) but your idea is good too, I just need to get true or false if not exists :)

Comment: @Alexxosipov `has()` is a wrapper for `offsetExists()`. `has()` converts the key into an array, then iterates over it and calls `offsetExists()`. And yes, you can use this method too.

Comment: Thanks for you help.